# Taurus execution on a remote host(aws)

Tags: amazon-web-services, taurus

(New to Taurus)
I am able to execute the tests using Taurus from local machine.
But I want to run these tests on a remote aws instance (JMeter should run on aws).
Pls let me know what the config(.yml file entries) for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing specific has to be there in the yml file.

Make sure that you have all the related jmeter files along with their test data if any on the ec2 box & then execute the bzt file.

Comment: But, as I am triggering the run through Jenkins, Its executing all scripts in local host.
Requirement is to run the performance test in a remote(aws instance) host. How/where can I provide the host details?